# Segmentation fault in Cython

Tags: cython

I am new to Cython. I have written a pyx file that returns a 2D Numpy or a memoryview array.

Here is the pyx code:

```py
import numpy as np
import cython
cimport numpy as np
from libc.math cimport int

@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.nonecheck(False)

cdef class TwoDMatrix():
    ''' make a two dimensional matrix '''

    cdef int N

    def __init__(self,N):
        self.N = N

    cpdef twoD(self, int [:,:] vector,str array):
        if array == 'numpy':
            state = 2*np.random.randint(2,size=(self.N,self.N))-1
            return state
        else:
            vec=self.initialise(vector,self.N)
            return vec

    cdef int [:,:] initialise(self, int [:,:] s,k) :
        cdef int i,j

        for i in range(k+1):
            for j in range(k+1):
                if np.random.rand() <0.5:
                    s[i,j] = -1
                else:
                    s[i,j] = 1

        return s
```

And here is the main py file where I give input:

```py
import numpy as np
import main

def matrix():
    N = 10
    vector = main.TwoDMatrix(N)

    spin = np.zeros((N,N),dtype=np.int32)

    print(f"from numpy: {vector.twoD(spin,'numpy')}")
    print(f"from memoryview: {vector.twoD(spin,'memoryview')}")

    print("program successfully exited")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    matrix()
```

The problem is for N >5 , when I run in terminal it always shows a segmentation fault(core dumped) message at the bottom. And for N>1, a similar following message is shown:

> "corrupted size vs. prev_size while consolidating
> Aborted (core dumped)"

Why is this message popping up? Is there anything that I should consider about memory allocation?

Comment: One thing to try would be to turn `boundscheck`on again. It's an optimization that you apply once you know that everything work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The segmentation fault is due to **out-of-bounds accesses**. Indeed, you create matrices of size `(N,N)` while `initialise` iterate over range `range(0, k+1)` where `k=N`. Thus you need to either use bigger matrices or to fix the two nested loops so to iterate over `range(0, k)` / `range(0, N)`.

Comment: And to emphasise: the out-of-bounds accesses are a crash-problem (rather than an `IndexError`-with-a-traceback-pointing-to-the-exact-location-problem) because OP has deliberately turned `boundscheck` off.